# Equivalent of GitLab's "before_script" for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gitlab

I'm looking for Jenkins' equivalent of the `before_script` keyword provided by GitLab.

So far what I found is the `input` keyword that you can use before entering the `steps` part of the stage, but this feature needs a prompt, whereas I only want to perform a `cd`.

Is there a Jenkins equivalent of GitLab's `before_script`keyword?

Comment: If my memory is correct, you cannot put build steps outside of a `steps` block with declarative Pipeline.  However, you can with scripted Pipeline.

Comment: May I ask for the purpose of a "cd" as a preliminary step to the whole build process? Could you not just re-configure the whole build process?

Comment: @triplem The Git project involves different languages. I'm at the stage where I want to perform statistical analysis on the Python modules. The `cd` command is solely here to navigate to the folder that contains all the Python code. But maybe that's useless?

Comment: Sounds like this is just a navigation for one step, isn't it?

Comment: I do this `cd` for like half a dozen stages. Not a big deal but since I come from using GitLab and are new to Jenkins I wanted to know whether there was an equivalent. It's just pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jenkins provided step [dir()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory) which changes the directory to one relative to the Jenkins `env.WORKSPACE` (`/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JOB_NAME` by default).

```
stage('Build') { 
    steps {
        dir('path/to/dir') {
            // do stuff
        }

        dir('path/to/other/dir') {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for `before_script`. However you can define a function in your pipeline and call it in the begining of each stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                cd
                // 
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                 cd
                // 
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') { 
            steps {
                 cd
                // 
            }
        }
    }
}

def cd() {
   //your code
}
```

When you want to use your function in other pipelines as well you might want to look into [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, that is actually how I'm handling it. My question was on the existence of an equivalent to GitLab's `before_script`, though. The cd command was an example of context.

Comment: Yeah as far as I have seen there is no equivalent